# Can I create a new membership for an existing contact using CiviCRM Drupal Webforms?

Tags: webform-civicrm

I am using CiviCRM's webform module for Drupal and I'd like to be able of setting it up a form that does the following:

1. locate the **existing contact** rather than creating a new one,
2. **add a new membership** record for the contact (no matter if the contact has already one or more memberships).

If I set the form by checking **existing contact** (or by setting a deduplication rule), as soon as the form is submitted, CiviCRM will try to find an existing contact and will do the same thing for the membership.

This means that for contacts with existing memberships, their membership records are updated rather than new membership records being created for those contacts.

- Am I maybe missing an **existing membership** checkbox somewhere?
- Is there a way, without coding, so I can create a new membership for an existing contact using CiviCRM Drupal Webforms?

Comment: CiviCRM was built on the logic that a contact would only have one Membership. There are work arounds for this, such as having the Membership Types associated with a different Organisation. Can you flesh out the scenario where somebody with an existing Membership would add a second Membership to their record.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the possible workaround of using a "different organization" but I tested it and it seems to do the job for us. A few screens will be developed to facilitate the revision of those new memberships and their transition to memberships of the final (real) organization.

Answer (score 1):

CiviCRM was built on the logic that a contact would only have one Membership. There are work arounds for this, such as having the Membership Types associated with a different Organisation. This makes it easier to have someone  hold several memberships at the same time.